# CSS Z-Index: -1

Tags: css, position, z-index, pseudo-element

I have an element, in this case an li and have positioned it relative and then have an :after pseudo element from it. It has "" content, positioned absolutely, has a position and dimesions and a box shadow. I have set it's z-index to -1 and the problem is that it's dropping right back to be the bottom most z-indexed element on my page. I expect it to drop back 1 place so to be just behind the li.

I am following this: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/

Any ideas? If I set the pseudo's z-index to be 1, then it jumps infront of the li, I just want it one stop behind it instead.

Comment: Could you please see what happens if you apply a `z-index:1` property to the `li`?

Comment: Doing that makes the pseudo element jump up ontop of the li. I'm just going to strip back all styles and see if anything on the site could be interfering. Will report back. Just tried a simplified case on Codepen and it's fine: http://cdpn.io/Kinvj so it's not a "it cannot be done problem"

Comment: That is expected behavior. I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: Found the issue, I needed z-index: 1; on my overall .container element. Solves it perfectly.

Comment: Revised my answer: evidently using `-1` doesn't mean the element shows up behind whatever it is being stacked relative to. You could change the z-index of the pseudo to 0 and the z-index of the li to 1, and still see the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z-index of an element positions it relative to the nearest stacking context, not necessarily a parent. Additionally, no element can be rendered *behind* the stacking context, regardless of whether you specify a negative z-index value (except in FF2, apparently). If you intend for the pseudoelement to show up behind the `li`, the element that is an ancestor of the `li` must create a stacking context.

Now, an element only creates a stacking context if one of the following conditions is true (taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)):

- the element is the root element (HTML),
- it is positioned (absolutely or relatively) **with a z-index value other than
  "auto"**,
- it has an opacity value less than 1. (See the specification
  for opacity)

As you might have noticed, explicitly specifying a value for the `z-index` property of the container of the `li` (other than "auto") resolves the problem. This is because the container now creates its own stacking context, and all descendants for which it is the nearest stacking context will be arranged according to their `z-index` values *relative* to the container.

Comment: Thanks. Understood and makes perfect sense!